# There is an error with async being the problem

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

It comes up an async error. The code I am using is below. I have even added async message yet there is still an error? I have searched it up yet there have been no answers.

```
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'ban':
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
          return message.channel.send("You cannot use this command.")
        }
        member = message.mentions.members.first(); 
        if (!member) {
          message.react("❌");
          return message.channel.send("Missing arguments. -ban @user Reason");
        } 

        reason = args.slice(1).join(" "); 
        if (!reason) reason = "Please provide a reason."; 

        await member
        .ban(reason) 
        message.react("✔️");
        embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setTitle("You banned them.")
        .setDescription(`${member} is banned forever. He he`)
        .addFields(
          {name: 'reason', value: reason}
        )
        .setFooter("You banned someone.");
        message.channel.send(embed);
      };
});
```

Comment: I have never used discord.js but this doesn't look like valid code `await member.ban(reason)message.react("✔️");`. Shouldn't there be a semicolon after the `.ban()` function?

Comment: What specific error are you getting? Add the error message to your code, and if possible, the line of the code that is triggering the error. This information will greatly assist us in solving your problem. Consider also posting more of your code, including the `client.on("message")` part of it.

Answer (score 1):

After `member.ban()` there should be a semi-colon and ideally a new line. You've not shown the function it is enclosed in, but it must be an async function, as a normal function cannot contain the word `await`. To make an async function, rather than doing `function runCommand() {  }`, simply you instead do `async function runCommand() {  }`

This is because an async function, as the name asynchronous suggests, runs asynchronous to everything else, so at the same time as. A normal function runs on its own, so if you put a wait in a normal function, it would cause the whole bot to sort of freeze while it waits for it.